# Bash, mail y caracteres especiales

Tags: linux, bash, email, terminal

Les comento, yo estoy enviando un mail de esta manera:

```
 mail -s "$(echo -e "$ASUNTO \nContent-Type: text/html")" $DESTINATARIO  < cuerpo.html
```

El mensaje me llega bárbaro, el problema esta en que la variable $ASUNTO tiene como contenido: "¡Cumpleaños en Zicco!" y al tener una Ñ se rompe y queda Â¡CumpleaÃ±os en Zicco!

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer para que funcione? Si lo envió manualmente el script toma perfecto las eñe, pero si lo croneo deja de funcionar y lo envia con ese error visual.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que definir el formato en los metadatos.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Podes definirla en tu variable de la siguiente manera:

"¡Cumplea&ntildeos en Zicco!";

Comment: Agrege esa linea en el html pero sigue igual, si pongo una ñ aparece Ã±

Comment: edité la respuesta

Comment: Mi variable de ASUNTO es la siguiente: ASUNTO="¡Cumplea&ntildeos en Zicco!"  y al enviar el mail el asunto dice: ¡Cumplea&ntildeos en Zicco! .. Como dato positivo antes por poner el signo de exclamacion (¡) me ponia una A mayuscula por delante y ahora no lo hace

Comment: Sabes que si ejecturo a mano el sh lo toma perfecto? con ñ y todo, pero si lo ejecuto por medio del cron el asunto dice: **Â¡CumpleaÃ±os en Zicco!** Como que el tema esta cuando se ejecuta por medio del cron..estara perdiendo la referencia del encoding ?